# Application of Nakayama Lemma?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

One of the application of Nakayama lemma proves that:

> If $(R,m)$ is a local ring and $M$ finitely generated $R$-module. Let $\{m_1,\dots,m_n\}$ be elements of $M$ such that image of $m_i$ under natural map is basis of $M/\mathfrak{m}M$. Then $\{m_1,\dots,m_n\}$ generates $M$.

Is it true that $\{m_1,\dots,m_n\}$ is also minimal generating set for $M$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The assumptions imply $\dim M/\mathfrak mM=n$, i.e. any set of generators of $M$ must at least have $n$ elements, because there residue classes generate a $n$-dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not the minimal generation set, when you use Nakayama lemma you can not get the contraction from the equation $m_{j}=\sum_{i\neq j}^{n}r_{i}m_{i}$.